# Dynamically loading JavaScript files in both browser and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, lazy-loading

My JavaScript library needs to be able to load optional scripts dynamically. I know of several ways to do this, but my library should be functional in both browsers and Node.js, and I wouldn't like to generate multiple versions. I also wouldn't like to reinvent the wheel.

Is there a recommended technique for targeting both platforms with the same code?

Comment: Unless you've tried something, this is not a good question for StackOverflow. Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ But here's a library that lets you use `require` on the client also http://browserify.org/

Comment: @JuanMendes - This would likely get closed as Too Broad on Progs.

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm sometimes confused about that. I thought the point of StackOverflow was to create a comprehensive Q&A database. This seems like a useful question for others, so I asked it here. I'm currently searching for a solution, and will answer my own question when I find something.

Comment: @JuanMendes you might want to read [What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/40980).  A question that is too broad here, or asking for a library recommendation would get closed for the same reason on Programmers.SE.

Comment: @mhelvens every StackExchange site has an [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page describing what you can ask about. Additionally, questions need to be answerable, hence the "too broad" comment by Glen.

Comment: @mhelvens Comprehensive for specific questions on how to get some code working. Questions that usually have one single correct answer. There are so many different ways to answer your question.

Comment: @JuanMendes I could add some example code, but that seems a bit pointless when the question can be posed in a more general way. I know about the on-topic page, and my question seems to qualify under the category of "specific programming problem". I don't see it falling under any of the off-topic points.

Comment: @mhelvens Too broad, there are too many possible correct answers

Comment: I retracted my close vote because I think the last sentence of the question can be answered appropriately for this forum (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

The browser and node.js load script files in fundamentally different ways.  The browser requires you to add script tags or to use ajax to fetch the code and then evaluate it with `eval()` or a Function object.  node.js has `require()` or the code can be fetched using other node.js I/O mechanisms and then evaluate it similarly.

There is no single way of loading code that works in both a browser and node.js.

So, to write a single function that would load some code in either environment, you would have to detect your environment and then use the appropriate approach for the environment.  This would not require two versions of your code, only a function that branched based on the detected environment and then executed the appropriate code for that environment.

This branching can be hidden behind a single function (pseduo-code):

```
function loadLibrary(name, doneFn) {
    if (node.js detected) {
        // fetch the code using node.js I/O
        // and then evaluate the code
        // notify caller when the script has finished loading
    } else {
        // fetch the code by inserting script tags into the DOM
        // notify caller when the script has finished loading
    }
}
```

This would be a recommended approach for targeting both platforms with a single piece of code.